# Pass arguments in nested function to update default arguments

Tags: r, arguments

I have nested functions and wish to pass arguments to the deepest function. That deepest function will already have default arguments, so I will be updating those argument values.

My mwe is using `plot()`, but in reality I'm working with `png()`, with default height and width arguments.

Any suggestions?

```
f1 <- function(...){ f2(...)}

f2 <- function(...){ f3(...)}

f3 <- function(...){ plot(xlab="hello1", ...)}

#this works
f1(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),type='b')

# I want to update the default xlab value, but it fails:
f1(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),type='b', xlab='hello2')
```

Comment: What about `f3 <- function(myxlab = 'hello1', ...) { plot(xlab = myxlab, ...) }`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `f3()`, `"hello1"` is not a default value for `xlab` in the list of function's formal arguments. It is instead the supplied value in the function body, so there's no way to override it:

```
f3 <- function(...){ plot(xlab="hello1", ...)}
```

I suspect you meant instead to do something like this.

```
f1 <- function(...){ f2(...)}
f2 <- function(...){ f3(...)}
f3 <- function(..., xlab="hello1") plot(..., xlab=xlab)

## Then check that it works
par(mfcol=c(1,2))
f1(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),type='b')
f1(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),type='b', xlab='hello2')
```

[image]

(Do notice that the formal argument `xlab` **must** follow the `...` argument here, so that it can only be matched exactly (and not by partial matching). Otherwise, in the absence of an argument named `xlab`, it'll  get matched by an argument named `x`, potentially (and actually here) causing you a lot of grief.)

Comment: Thanks Josh. I think this is simple solution.

Comment: @mfolkes Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

My usual approach for modifying arguments in `...` is as follows:

```
f1 = function(...) {
  dots = list(...)
  if (!('ylab' %in% names(dots))) {
    dots$ylab = 'hello'
  }
  do.call(plot, dots)
}
# check results 
f1(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) 
f1(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), ylab = 'hi')
```

What happens here is that `...` is captured in a list called `dots`. Next, R checks if this list `dots` contains any information about `ylab`. If there is no information, we set it to a specified value. If there is information, we do nothing. Last, `do.call(a, b)` is a function that basically stands voor execute function `a` with arguments `b`.

## edit

This works better with multiple default arguments (and probably also better in general).

```
f1 = function(...) {
  # capture ... in a list
  dots = list(...)
  # default arguments with their values
  def.vals = list(bty = 'n', xlab = 'hello', las = 1)
  # find elements in dots by names of def.vals. store those that are NULL
  ind = unlist(lapply(dots[names(def.vals)], is.null))
  # fill empty elements with default values 
  dots[names(def.vals)[ind]] = def.vals[ind]
  # do plot
  do.call(plot, dots)
}

f1(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), ylab = 'hi', bty = 'l')
```

Comment: This is really helpful. But I guess if I was updating multiple default arguments, I'd need to have an `if(){}` for each argument?

Comment: Wow, that edit addition is...pretty impressive. I'll put that in my back pocket. Thanks again.